# Group by every N rows within a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to group every N rows within each group of a SQL table, the best answer I've found is this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/66806186/10916933 but my data is also grouped by another identifier (Batch) and I would like to start a new GroupID every time the identifier changes. Batches are not of a consistent size.

This is what I get currently (N = 2 for display purposes, it is actually 1000):

| Batch | Value | RowID | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10.2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 6.7 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 7.6 | 3 | 2 |
| B | 7.0 | 4 | 2 |
| B | 10.2 | 5 | 3 |
| C | 9.6 | 6 | 3 |
| C | 8.2 | 7 | 4 |
| C | 1.1 | 8 | 4 |
| C | 0.3 | 9 | 5 |
| C | 9.0 | 10 | 5 |
| C | 10.2 | 11 | 6 |

This is what I want (i.e. when Batch B starts, it gives me a new GroupID even though there has only been one):

| Batch | Value | RowID | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10.2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 6.7 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 7.6 | 3 | 2 |
| B | 7.0 | 4 | 3 |
| B | 10.2 | 5 | 3 |
| C | 9.6 | 6 | 4 |
| C | 8.2 | 7 | 4 |
| C | 1.1 | 8 | 5 |
| C | 0.3 | 9 | 5 |
| C | 9.0 | 10 | 6 |
| C | 10.2 | 11 | 6 |

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using? MS Sql Server, MySql, Postgresql, something else?

Comment: Apologies, MS Sql Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can indicate where a group starts using `lag()` and row number arithmetic.  Then do a cumulative sum.  A new group starts on the odd numbered rows of each batch:

```
select t.*,
       sum(is_start) over (order by batch, rowid) as groupid
from (select t.*,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by batch order by rowid) % 2 = 1
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as is_start
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon has the answer. Toss him that checkmark. Here's a slightly adjusted version:

```
CREATE TABLE batches (
    Batch   VARCHAR(4)
  , Value   DECIMAL(5, 2)
  , RowID   int
  , GroupID int
);

INSERT INTO batches VALUES
  ('A' , 10.2 , 1 , 1 )
, ('A' ,  6.7 , 2 , 1 )
, ('A' ,  7.6 , 3 , 2 )
, ('B' ,  7.0 , 4 , 2 )
, ('B' , 10.2 , 5 , 3 )
, ('C' ,  9.6 , 6 , 3 )
, ('C' ,  8.2 , 7 , 4 )
, ('C' ,  1.1 , 8 , 4 )
, ('C' ,  0.3 , 9 , 5 )
, ('C' ,  9.0 ,10 , 5 )
, ('C' , 10.2 ,11 , 6 )
;

WITH xrows AS (
       SELECT t.*
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Batch ORDER BY RowID) % 2 AS is_start
         FROM batches AS t
     )
SELECT t.*
     , SUM(is_start) OVER (ORDER BY Batch, RowID) AS new_GroupID
  FROM xrows AS t
 ORDER BY RowID
;

Result:

+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| Batch | Value | RowID | GroupID | is_start | new_GroupID |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| A     | 10.20 |     1 |       1 |        1 |           1 |
| A     |  6.70 |     2 |       1 |        0 |           1 |
| A     |  7.60 |     3 |       2 |        1 |           2 |
| B     |  7.00 |     4 |       2 |        1 |           3 |
| B     | 10.20 |     5 |       3 |        0 |           3 |
| C     |  9.60 |     6 |       3 |        1 |           4 |
| C     |  8.20 |     7 |       4 |        0 |           4 |
| C     |  1.10 |     8 |       4 |        1 |           5 |
| C     |  0.30 |     9 |       5 |        0 |           5 |
| C     |  9.00 |    10 |       5 |        1 |           6 |
| C     | 10.20 |    11 |       6 |        0 |           6 |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

[Full test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af1f1efa42c55521ed66f140eba77040)

Comment: Great example, thanks. For anyone copying this, it misses the CASE WHEN if group size is not 2 :)

Comment: @PharmDataSci The new_GroupID column gets it right.  I left in the old / not correct GroupID column, for comparison.